# Summarize using condition for a single column

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, summarize

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(HELP = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"))
```

I did:

```
cdata <- ddply(df, c("HELP"), summarise,
           Total = sum(df$HELP == 'No'),
           Probability = Total/nrow(df))
```

but to the value to "Yes" stay the same value that "No". I tried to use "if" condition but didn't work.

What I want to do is to summarize, by Help, where it would have the sum of `df.help == "No"` and the sum of `df.help == "Yes"`, and their respective probabilities.

The end result should look something like this:

```
|    | Help | Total | Probability  |
|----|------|-------|--------------|
|  1 | Yes  | 4     | 0.666        |
|  2 | No   | 2     | 0.333        |
```

What is the appropriate way to go about this with ddply or other way?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `dplyr`, as you tagged. This allows you to easily group your data using `group_by`, and using using `summarise` and `mutate` you can add new columns to achieve your desired result.

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(HELP) %>% summarise(Total = n()) %>% mutate(Probability = Total / sum(Total))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
    HELP Total Probability
  <fctr> <int>       <dbl>
1     No     2   0.3333333
2    Yes     4   0.6666667
```

## Explanation

`%>%` forwards the output from the command on the left, to the command on the right of the operator. You can chain several commands behind eachother, but while that works it can quickly become a mess to read.

`group_by(HELP)` will divide your data frame in to those rows with identical values in `HELP`. It can also take several columns.

`summarise(Total = n())` -- `n()` is another `dplyr` function, that is set to the number of rows in your group. In both `summarise` and `mutate` new column names are provided **without** `'` or `"`

`mutate(Probability = Total / sum(Total))` -- simple calculation, based on the results just calculated in the step before

Comment: thank you! I understood all of your explanations and were of great help to me.

Comment: Your' welcome! If the answer was helpful please indicate that by accepting, unless you're still looking for a ddply way?!